# How to insert values into one table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables i.e., `table1` and `table2` with same structure and I want to insert all the values of table1 into table2. These table contains two image type column. I have tried this query but couldn't succeed.

```
DECLARE @imagepan VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @imagecheque VARBINARY(MAX)

SET @imagepan=(SELECT panid FROM table1 WHERE Emp_code='E001')
SET @imagecheque=(SELECT cancel_checqe FROM table1 WHERE Emp_code='E001')
INSERT INTO table2 
    (transno, Emp_code, PanNo, panid, panext, entdt_pan, banknm, 
    cancel_checqe, chqExt, entDt_bnk, Acc_No, IFSC, Cheque_nm, status_pan1, 
    status_pan, status_bnk1, status_bnk, userid, entdt, panModify_by, 
    panModify_on, bnkModify_by, bnkModify_on) 
VALUES
    (SELECT 
        transno, Emp_code, PanNo, @imagepan, panext, entdt_pan, 
        banknm, @imagecheque, chqExt, entDt_bnk, Acc_No, IFSC, Cheque_nm, 
        status_pan1, status_pan, status_bnk1, status_bnk, userid, entdt, 
        panModify_by, panModify_on, bnkModify_by, bnkModify_on 
    FROM 
        table1 
    WHERE 
        Emp_code='E001')
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table1 (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM table2` remove `values (` from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove 'values' keyword

```
insert into table2 (transno, Emp_code, PanNo, panid, panext, entdt_pan, 
                    banknm, cancel_checqe, chqExt, entDt_bnk, Acc_No, 
                    IFSC, Cheque_nm, status_pan1, status_pan, 
                    status_bnk1, status_bnk, userid, entdt, panModify_by, 
                    panModify_on, bnkModify_by, bnkModify_on) 
    select 
        transno, Emp_code, PanNo, @imagepan, panext, entdt_pan, 
        banknm, @imagecheque, chqExt, entDt_bnk, Acc_No, 
        IFSC, Cheque_nm, status_pan1, status_pan, 
        status_bnk1, status_bnk, userid, entdt, panModify_by, 
        panModify_on, bnkModify_by, bnkModify_on 
    from 
        table1 
    where 
        Emp_code = 'E001';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `values (` and closing `)` at the end:

```
DECLARE @imagepan VARBINARY(MAX);
DECLARE @imagecheque VARBINARY(MAX);

SET @imagepan = (SELECT panid FROM table1 WHERE Emp_code = 'E001');
SET @imagecheque = (SELECT cancel_checqe FROM table1 WHERE Emp_code = 'E001');

INSERT INTO table2 (transno, Emp_code, PanNo, panid, panext, entdt_pan, 
banknm, cancel_checqe, chqExt, entDt_bnk, Acc_No, IFSC, Cheque_nm, 
status_pan1, status_pan, status_bnk1, status_bnk, userid, entdt, 
panModify_by, panModify_on, bnkModify_by, bnkModify_on) 
SELECT transno, Emp_code, PanNo, @imagepan, panext, entdt_pan, 
banknm, @imagecheque, chqExt, entDt_bnk, Acc_No, IFSC, Cheque_nm, 
status_pan1, status_pan, status_bnk1, status_bnk, userid, entdt, 
panModify_by, panModify_on, bnkModify_by, bnkModify_on 
FROM table1 
WHERE Emp_code='E001';
```